# Javascript code to increase element height works in console, but not as a bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I have the following code to change the height of a box on the fly:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("tox tox-tinymce")[0].style.height = '700px';
```

If I put this in the console, it works as expected. Then I make it a bookmarklet like so

```js
javascript:(function(){document.getElementsByClassName("tox tox-tinymce")[0].style.height = '700px'})()

// Also tried this using a bookmarklet converter online
// javascript:(function()%7Bdocument.getElementsByClassName(%22tox%20tox-tinymce%22)%5B0%5D.style.height%20%3D%20'700px'%7D)()
```

When I click the bookmark, I get the following error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'style')**

This was working a week ago, but suddenly doesn't. I have no idea why.

One thing I tried was walking the dom one level at a time like so:

```js
all = document.querySelectorAll('body')[0];
console.log(all);
macro=all.querySelectorAll('*')[0]; 
console.log(macro).
editbox = macro.querySelectorAll('*')[0]; 
console.log(editbox)
```

The result of all is "</body" and the result of macro is the first element on the page - some kind of outer wrapper tag named <macropotent-somethingsomething...>

But the macropotent thing doesn't respond properly and querying it with querySelectorAll returns in NodeList[] (empty list).

Comment: The error message indicates that `document.getElementsByClassName("tox tox-tinymce")` isn't finding any matching elements. Something must have changed so those classes don't match any more.

Comment: On an unrelated note, since this is just a one-liner you don't really need the function wrapper. `javascript:(document.getElementsByClassName("tox tox-tinymce")[0]?.style.height = '700px')` should work, too, with that `?` preventing the rest of the chain from running if there is no matching element found.

Comment: I tested your code and it works, even as a bookmarklet. Is it possible that the element you are trying to reach is not ready yet?

Comment: @E-telier It's definitely ready. I can run the code in console, change the height, click the bookmark and the console version works while the bookmarklet doesn't

Comment: There's an outer HTML element around the tiny-mce stuff called <macropotent-somethingsomething> that seems to be messing with the dom.

Comment: All, I was able to fix it by opening a version of the page that gets rid of the application wrapper (header). Whatever fancy nonsense the outer wrapper added is gone and the bookmark works. This appears to be a problem with Servicenow in general.